# How can I show that this function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

> Define $f : M \rightarrow CM_i$ where $M$ is an m-simplex $M = [p_0, \dots, p_m]$ and $M_i = [p_0, \dots, \hat p_i, \dots,  p_m]$ is the $i$-face of the simplex $M$ and let $C$ be the cone and
>
> Define $f$ explicitly by $f(\sum t_j p_j) = [\sum_{j \neq i}\frac{t_j}{1-t_i}p_j, t_i]$ if $t_i \neq 1$ and $[p_i, 1]$ if $t_i = 1$, then $f$ is continuous.

I'm having a difficult time trying to prove this.  I know I have to show:

If $U \in T_{CM_i}$ (open in the topology), then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $T_{M}$, but I can't figure anywhere past this.  I know that $U \in T_{CM_i}$ iff $v^{-1}(U) \in T_{M_i \times I}$, but I don't see how I could use this any further.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Although you do not mention it, the simplex $M$ is the convex hull of $m+1$ points $p_0,\ldots,p_m \in \mathbb R^N$ in *general position* (which means that the set  $\mathcal B_0 = \{p_1-p_0,\ldots,p_m-p_0\}$ of $m$ difference vectors is linearly independent; this requires $N \ge m$). Also note that  $p_0,\ldots,p_m$ are in general position iff the set $\mathcal B_i = \{ p_j - p_i \mid j \in \{0,\ldots, m\} \setminus \{i\} \}$ is linearly independent for *some* $i \in \{0,\ldots, m\}$ iff *all* $\mathcal B_i$ are linearly independent.

$f$ is not well-defined since $p_i \notin M_i$ and thus $[p_i,1]$ cannot be a point of $CM_i$. A correct definition is $f(p_i) = *$, where $*$ is the tip of the cone, i.e. the common equivalence class of all $(x,1)$ with $x \in M_i$. Note that in $x = \sum t_j p_j$ we have $t_i =1$ iff $x = p_i$.

For $x \in M$ we have $x = \sum t_jp_j$ with $t_j \ge 0$ and $\sum t_j = 1$. These $t_j$ are called the *barycentric coordinates* of $x$ wit respect to $p_0,\ldots,p_m$. They are uniquely determined by $x$: We have $\sum t_jp_j = (1-\sum_{j > 0}t_j)p_0 + \sum_{j > 0}t_j p_j = p_0 + \sum_{j > 0}t_j(p_j-p_0)$. Thus, if $\sum t_jp_j = \sum s_jp_j$, then $\sum_{j > 0}t_j(p_j-p_0) = \sum_{j > 0}s_j(p_j-p_0)$ which implies $t_j = s_j$ for $j > 0$ and hence also $t_0 = s_0$.

The purpose of your question is to find a homeomorphism $M \to CM_i$. We do it the other way and construct a homeomorphism $g : CM_i \to M$ (whose inverse will be $f$). Define
$$\phi : \mathbb R^N \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^N, \phi(x,t) = (1-t) x  +t p_i .$$
This is a continuous map.

1. $\phi(M_i \times I) \subset M$: Let $x = \sum_{j \ne i} t_j p_j \in M_i$, where
   the $t_j$ are the barycentric coordinates of $x$ with respect to the vertices of $M_i$. Then $(1-t) x  +t p_i = \sum_{j \ne i}(1-t)t_j p_j + t p_i$ where $(1-t)t_j \ge 0, t \ge 0$ and $\sum_{j \ne i}(1-t)t_j + t = (1-t)\sum_{j \ne i} t_j + t = 1-t + t = 1$, i.e. $\phi(x,t) \in M$.
2. $\phi(M_i \times I) = M$: Let $y = \sum s_jp_j \in M$ with barycentric coordinates $s_j$. If $y = p_i$, then $\phi(x,1) = y$ for all $x \in M_i$. If $y \ne p_i$, then $1 > s_i \ge 0$, $\frac{s_j}{1-s_i} \ge 0$ and $\sum_{j \ne i} \frac{s_j}{1-s_i} = \frac{1}{1-s_i} \sum_{j \ne i} s_j = \frac{1}{1-s_i} (1-s_i) = 1$, therefore $x =  \sum_{j \ne i} \frac{s_j}{1-s_i} p_j \in M_i$ and $\phi(x,s_i) = y$.
3. $\phi(x,t) = \phi(x',t')$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(x,t) = (x',t')$ or $t = t' = 1$: $\Leftarrow$ is obvious. $\Rightarrow$: Let $\phi(x,t) = \phi(x',t')$ which means that $(1-t)x +  tp_i = (1-t')x' + t' p_i$. Due to the uniqueness of barycentric coordinates for points of $M$ we get $t = t' = \tau$ and hence $(1-\tau) x = (1 -\tau) x'$. If $\tau < 1$, then clearly $x = x'$.

Therefore $\phi$ induces a continuous bijection
$$g : CM_i = M_i \times I / M_i \times \{1\} \to M .$$
This map is a homeomorphism because $M_i$ is compact, hence also the cone $CM_i$ is compact, and $M$ is Hausdorff.

By construction we have $f = g^{-1}$.